# Implementing a CRC check within Android SMS Functionality

Tags: android, sms, crc

I am fairly new to android , but I dont see how it is possible to implement a CRC check, or some kind of message integrity check for a SMS sent from one Android device to another. I'm busy looking at XOR Checksum computations , but I am not sure If I am moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use MD5 or some other built-in hash mechanism.

http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.security/Digest.html

Comment: I need to use something like CRC32 or Alder32